# What kind of object is pictured in these two Roman fresco wall paintings?

Tags: ancient-history, roman-empire, identification

[image][image]Both are paintings in the same house near Naples. They were excavated from the ashes of the [eruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eruption_of_Mount_Vesuvius_in_79) of Mt. Vesuvius.

Apparently, they picture the same kind of object. But what is it?

Comment: You need to click that small Number/Link at the bottom. I might delete one of the other two though, to make it easier. I tried to add more "overview" pictures as well, but stackexchange would not accept the file size.

Answer (score 14):

These images are from the [Villa Poppaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villa_Poppaea), and seem to represent an ornamental torch used in Roman religious rites. The first image is from the base of a full wall fresco shown [here](http://creadm.solent.ac.uk/custom/rwpainting/ch8/ch.8.4.1.html) representing a view of a sacrificial tripod resting on a column:[image]

The image from the question is a bit distorted, but you can see and read more [here](http://creadm.solent.ac.uk/custom/rwpainting/ch8/ch.8.4.4.html), where the [item is described](http://creadm.solent.ac.uk/custom/rwpainting/ch8/ch.8.4.html) as (emphasis mine) a

> 'Villa di Poppea, Oplontis, room 15, detail from a wall-painting
>   depicting the **torch of Apollo** and a sacrificial bucranium (bull's
>   skull)'

So it appears this is an ornate torch, probably meant specifically to start sacrificial fires in worship of Apollo.  (More about the [bucranium here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucranium), which can be seen better in the answer by sempaiscuba).

---

The second image, from a different room, may represent a similar sacrificial scene. From [this article](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/secondary/SMIGRA*/Sacrificium.html) discussing sacrifices:

> A third class of unbloody sacrifices consisted of fruit and cakes. The
>   former were mostly offered to the gods as primitiae or tithes of the
>   harvest, and as a sign of gratitude.

The second image seems to represent this type of scene, showing the fruits and cakes waiting to be sacrificed to ensure a good harvest.

Comment: You beat me to the punch! +1 :-)

Comment: @sempaiscuba Same source even, funny. I wasn't sure about legality of image from there, so just did the link, probably the difference in time.

Comment: I did read the guide on [citing and referencing](http://library.soton.ac.uk/citing-and-referencing) from Southampton University (the source is from a site on their servers), and I think it's OK to post the image with attribution. I was trying to avoid the "link-only" type of answer.  If there is a problem I'm happy to remove the image and replace it with a link to their site.

Comment: @sempaiscuba should be ok to use then.

Answer (score 9):

The object is a "[Torch of Apollo](http://creadm.solent.ac.uk/custom/rwpainting/ch8/ch.8.4.4.html)":

[image: Torch of Appollo]

As Maurice Owen explains, this was [often used](http://creadm.solent.ac.uk/custom/rwpainting/ch8/ch.8.4.html) (along with other imagery) to indicate a sanctuary dedicated to the god Apollo.